# Linked List reversal

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, linked-list

Recursive version. The only interesting function:

```
        List& List::reverse()
        {
            if (empty())
            {   return *this;
            }
            int val = head();
            //
            // The fun bit.
            // See if you can figure this bit out.
            return pop().reverse().append(val);
        }
```

The rest:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
struct List
{
    struct Node
    {
        int     val;
        std::unique_ptr<Node>   next;
        Node(){}
        Node(int v, Node* oldTail)
            : val(v)
            , next(nullptr)
        {
            oldTail->next.reset(this);
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Node const& data)
        {
            return s << data.val << " ";
        }
    };
    Node    sentinal;
    Node*   tail;
    public:
        List()
            : tail(&sentinal)
        {}
        bool empty() const
        {
            return &sentinal == tail;
        }
        int& head()
        {
            // Pre-Condition not empty
            return sentinal.next->val;
        }
        List& append(int val)
        {
            tail = new Node(val, tail);
            return *this;
        }
        List& pop()
        {
            // Pre-Condition not empty
            sentinal.next.reset(sentinal.next->next.release());
            tail = sentinal.next.get() ? tail : &sentinal;
            return *this;
        }
        List& reverse();
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, List const& data)
        {
            for(Node* loop = data.sentinal.next.get(); loop != nullptr; loop=loop->next.get())
            {   s << *loop;
            }
            return s << "\n";
        }

};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> See if you can figure this bit out.

Is this meant to be a [Programming Puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)?

You don't call `append` until after you finish calling `reverse`; `reverse` is recursive; so all the `append` calls will be called after all the `reverse` calls: and that explains why `reverse` will eventually terminate i.e. why the list will eventually be empty.

From a code-review point of view:

1. I fear that a recursive implementation might exceed your finite maximum stack size if the list is long.
2. You're deleting and creating new Node objects; you might instead be able to do it in a way that reuses existing Node instances.

Also, it should be spelled "sentinel".

Comment: Fixed everything but recursion. Because thats the bit that makes it "fun".

Comment: Not a puzzle. Valid code needs checking. Just fun code. Now the next time somebody posts a singly linked list implementation I have a reference to point them to. :-)

Comment: @LokiAstari: "*Now the next time somebody posts a singly linked list implementation*"  Given the popularity of these implementations on this site, I hope you can keep up. ;-)

Comment: @LokiAstari: Also, it appears that you've made some changes based on this answer (at least pertaining to the spelling).  Please reverse those individual changes [as per site policy](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/can-i-edit-my-own-question-to-include-suggested-changes-from-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Some minor things:

- You could just leave out `public` since you're only dealing with `struct`s.  You could still maintain the following indentation to really keep it separate from the `Node` code.
- In C++11, you can now use `default` constructors if you still need your own:

  ```
  Node() = default;
  ```
- Consider making `List` a templated class if you'd like it to handle other types of values.